# VectorAngle returns complex angles

Tags: functions, numerics

The built-in `VectorAngle` function sometimes returns complex output when the actual angle is very close to `π`. The imaginary component is large enough and can't be removed by `Chop` with default tolerance:

```
VectorAngle[{0.034429687500000083, 0}, {-0.03442968749999986, 0}]
%//Chop
```

> ```
> 3.141592653589793` - 2.1073424338879928`*^-8 I 
>
> 3.141592653589793` - 2.1073424338879928`*^-8 I
> ```

For comparison, custom implementation works as expected:

```
vectorAngle[v1_, v2_] := ArcCos[v1.v2/(Norm[v1] Norm[v2])]

vectorAngle[{0.034429687500000083, 0}, {-0.03442968749999986, 0}]
```

> ```
> 3.141592653589793`
> ```

**From where comes imaginary part in the output? Is it a bug?**

Comment: Returning complex output means that the modulus of the argument inside `ArcCos` is greater than `1`. It may be because of `precision` of `VectorAngle`.

Comment: `(VectorAngle[{0.034429687500000083, 0}, {-0.03442968749999986, 0}]/
   Pi // RootApproximant)*Pi` evaluates to `Pi`

Comment: Did you try the alternative in my answer in the linked dupe?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it works perfectly (at least in my tests). It disappoints that the built-in is so numerically unstable.

Answer (score 3):

Use higher precision:

```
VectorAngle @@ SetPrecision[#, 20]& @ {
  {0.034429687500000083, 0}, {-0.03442968749999986, 0}}

(*  3.141592654  *)
```

**EDIT:** High precision isn't required, just setting a precision to avoid machine precision provides a real value:

```
Table[
 VectorAngle @@ SetPrecision[#, p] &@
  {{0.034429687500000083, 0},
   {-0.03442968749999986, 0}},
 {p, 5, 25, 5}]

(*  {3.1, 3.1416, 3.141593, 3.141592654, 3.14159265359}  *)
```